# Question regarding the Fourier Transform of the Hubbard Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, ferromagnetism

If you Fourier transform the Hubbard Hamiltonian
$$
H = \sum_{ij \sigma} T_{ij} c^{\dagger}_{i \sigma} c_{j \sigma} + \frac{U}{2} \sum_{i \sigma} n_{i \sigma} n_{i \overline{\sigma}}
$$
via
$$
c^{\dagger}_{i \sigma} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}} e^{-i \mathbf{k} \mathbf{r}_i} c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{k} \sigma}
$$
to the now transformed Hamiltonian
$$
H = \sum_{\mathbf{k} \sigma} \varepsilon(\mathbf{k}) c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{k} \sigma} c_{\mathbf{k} \sigma} + \frac{U}{2} \sum_{\mathbf{k} \mathbf{q} \mathbf{p} \sigma} c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q} \sigma} c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q} \overline{\sigma}} c_{\mathbf{k} \sigma} c_{\mathbf{p} \overline{\sigma}} 
$$
what is the physical interpretation of the second term? Since I can't connect the change in momenta in momentum space to the number operators in real space.

Comment: I think that the physical interpretation of the second term is more transparent in real space than in momentum space. In momentum space it is a little cumbersome: you have to sum all the 2-body collisions of particles with opposite spins and arbitrary momenta with the momentum conservation requirement that if one goes $p\to p-q$, the other one goes $k\to k+q$